# Google Chrome Developer Tools Scrambled Source

Tags: developer-tools, google-chrome

Is anyone aware of, experiencing or know how to fix this? It occurs on any page that I use developer tools on.. It looks as if the markup is being reprinted on top of itself instead of scrolling. Also, whatever element I have selected appears white (invisible). Please help!

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: Never seen this happen, but I suspect the long URLs have caused a buffer overflow.

Comment: Is this a public facing website where we can run it ourselves?

Comment: It isn't.. but I get the same issue on any website I go to that has javascript on it.